# What is the simplification for $\sum_k k (1-e^{-\lambda c})^k e^{-\lambda c}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am assuming this uses some kind of geometric or taylor series expansion but I am not able to see how to get it :$$\sum_k k (1-e^{-\lambda c})^k e^{-\lambda c}$$

Comment: Hint: can you sum $\sum\limits_kkt^k$?

Comment: I am not sure if I can, how would I go about doing that is the question I am asking (coming from a non mathematical background)?

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) should give you ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote $u=1-e^{-\lambda c},$ then 
$$
\sum_k k (1-e^{-\lambda c})^k e^{-\lambda c}=(1-u)u\sum_k {k u^{k-1} }=(1-u)u\left(\sum_k { u^{k} }\right)'.
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sum_\sum_{a\le k\le b} k (1-e^{-\lambda c})^k e^{-\lambda c} =e^{-\lambda c}\sum_{a\le k\le b} k (1-e^{-\lambda c})^k $$

Let $$\sum_{a\le r\le b}A x^r=Ax^a\frac{x^{b-a+1}-1}{x-1}=A\frac{x^{b+1}-x^a}{x-1}$$

Differentiate wrt $x$ and multiply both sides by $x$

Comment: I think $\sum_{0 \le r \le b-a} x^r = \dfrac{x^{b-a+1}-1}{x-1}$.

Comment: @martycohen, thanks for your observation. rectified